# OPTIONS Preflight causing POST request to hang

Tags: php, angular, cors, slim

I've been having issues with the CORS OPTIONS preflight request with my angular application. To be brief I'm trying to implement a simple login which sends a POST request to my server, which has a backend built using PHP\Slim, carrying the user's credentials. The CORS OPTIONS requests first and I handle it with slim to respond with a 200 OK, so when the browser gets the OK it finally sends my POST with the credentials, but then it just hangs...no response code, nothing.

Honestly, this is boggling my mind and I'm literally guessing there's something wrong with my request service because this is the only service sending an OPTIONS request, to begin with.

The crazy thing is that after I spam the login button, it eventually gives in and responds.

```
I checked the network requests and this is the idea of what it looks like:

200 OPTIONS
    POST
200 OPTIONS
    POST

the posts are just blank
```

This is my service.

```
  signin(user: User): Observable<Result> {
    return this._http.post<Result>( this.base + this.signinURL, user )
      .pipe(catchError(this.error));
  }

  private error(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return throwError(error);
  }
```

here's the CORS related routes

```
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    return $response->withStatus(200);
});
$app->add(function (Request $req, Response $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
});
$app->map(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH'], '/{routes:.+}', function(Request $req, Response $res) {
    $handler = $this->notFoundHandler;
    return $handler($req, $res);
});
```

Also worth mentioning is that I'm running the front-end on the Angular CLI server and the PHP on the PHP Server v7.3.

If someone could just explain to me what is happening and why I'd be happy, thanks for the thoughts...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client (browser) is what sends the OPTIONS request; this is done automatically by the browser before every request. An OPTIONS request simply tells the client what kind of request it's permitted to make (POST, GET, DELETE, etc). Note that I'm assuming your application is a web-application since your code does not demonstrate any explicit OPTIONS request being made.

As for the reason why you aren't seeing the POST body in Chrome, is unrelated to your service issues. This is a chrome specific thing; it basically has to do with page refreshes/redirects --- Chrome won't persist the post body. If you preserve the chrome log, and stop the network before any reload/refresh/redirect can take place, you'll see the body. There's a specific reason this happens i just cant recall where I read it. My advice is just to log this locally instead.

As for your API, your OPTIONS handling looks a little funny. `$app->options` is where you're catching all OPTIONS requests, and all you are doing is returning 200; you aren't defining your headers. Without testing, I'm assuming this is your issue.

I'd say drop all of that, and instead just do something like this:

```php
$app = new \Slim\App();

$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, $next) {
    if($request->getMethod() !== 'OPTIONS') {
        return $next($request, $response);
    }

    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', $request->getHeaderLine('Access-Control-Request-Method'));
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->getHeaderLine('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));

    return $next($request, $response);
});

# ... all your other routes ...

$app->run();
```

Alternatively, why not just let your http server handle the OPTIONS requests itself?

In my case, which I'll note i'm also running a Slim based API in PHP 7.3, I don't bother handling the OPTIONS request, I just set the headers in my virtual host configuration (apache2). Something like this:

```sh
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ...

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            # allowable request origins
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

            # allowable request types
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS"

            # how long to cache results of preflight requests
            Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1800"

            # allowable headers
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept"

            # permit preflight response requests using credentials
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
    </IfModule>

    ...

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks @Crayons, i just tried your solution for my slim file and it worked!...if i may ask further though, how i would set the config in a .htaccess file that slim uses. im worried that adding access control header together with the rewrite engine will break something on that front.

Comment: Thanks again @Crayons...I was actually running it off of firefox, the blank response was what was confusing me the most.

Comment: Setting the headers in either your virtual host, or through a .htaccess file will not interfere with your rewrite rules. I use both in my virtual host definitions. Just made sure in your apache server, that you've enabled both modules: `sudo a2enmod headers` and `sudo a2enmod rewrite`. You can add the header rules the same way in your .htaccess file `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS"` etc, etc.

Comment: got it!...the key word is 'add' Access-Control... not 'set'... thanks man for the assist, appreciate it

Comment: Just for information: setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * is not a good practice. It's recommended to define the hosts that are really allowed to consume the API. If it's a public API intended to be embedded by web apps (not server-side consuming), so I think it's OK to set it's value to *.